# Is there a way to update a xarray DataSet variable with a new one having new coordinates

Tags: python-xarray

Is there a way to update a xarray DataSet variable with a new one having new coordinates without dropping the variable or the dimension?

For instance, the line below allows me to update a dataset with dimensions `(date:732 ticker:2 variable:4 indicator:2)` to a dataset with dimensions `(date:732 ticker:2 variable:4 indicator:1)`. I, however, need to first drop the dimensions before setting the new coordinates.

```
ds.drop_dims('indicator').update({'indicators': (['date', 'ticker', 'indicator'], atr.data)}).assign_coords(indicator=['ATR'])
```